# nodejs phantomjs bridge, to send form and to get results

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, bridge

I'm using node.js with phantomjs by phantomjs-node bridge.
The question:
I open a page, e with the page.evaluate function I fill a form and I submit it.
Now I need to retrieve data from the page which have received form data, when this page is fully loaded. How should I do?

Thanks

The bridge: https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node